# How to load output of openGL glReadpixels() into bitmap memory

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, bitmap

I've written code to convert YUV to RGB using openGL ES 3.0. Instead of showing the converted image into glViewPort surface, i want to store it on bitmap memory.
I used openGL frame buffer and render buffer(render to texture), then trying to get the output using glReadpixels() function. I am getting output, but i dont know how to upload the output into bitmap memory. Please help.

Comment: Thanks, yes i'm using 2D image and using glTexImage2D() i sent my data from system memory to texture memory and done some process. Now i want to read the output after shaders and textures applied, for that i used glReadpixels(). Now i would like to use that output image on my screen

Answer (score 0):

If you have image data in client (system) memory, and want to send it to texture memory, you would use [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) (I'm assuming you have a 2D image).

However, if I'm understanding your use case, it's kind of a strange to render to render buffer, use glReadPixels to read the results it into system memory, and then use that data to create a new texture. Generally, you would just attach a texture as the color output for the framebuffer, and then use that directly. This would bypass the roundtrip to system memory, which is expensive.

Comment: i'm using three textures for y u and v components. If i attach those textures to Framebuffer, Framebuffer status is complete. but when i read the output from the framebuffer, i could not get the final RGB image. Instead it is reading any one of the texture input from framebuffer. I need to read the final output of YUV to RGB conversion to store it for further process

Comment: If you are converting YUV from 3 input textures in a shader into an RGB framebuffer, the YUV textures are should not be attached to the framebuffer, they should be uniform inputs to the shader.

Comment: So Actually i dont want the output in surface view. I need to store the output of YUV to RGB into buffer. Without attaching the textures to Framebuffer how can i access the output? Is any other way possible to fetch the YUV to RGB output from buffer?

Comment: Framebuffers are render targets. The default framebuffer (in the Android context) is the surface view's framebuffer, but you can create others to do "offscreen" rendering. Check out a basic render-to-texture tutorial.

Comment: I created framebuffer for offscreen rendering. created three textures(Y,U and V) componnents and attached those textures to Framebuffer. When i Fetch the final output from framebuffer using glReadPixels() , i'm getting only red color image. but i need to display RGB image. How to do that?

Comment: I've shared the code in the below path (using FBO in openGL ES) : http://www.filedropper.com/yuvtorgblogic_1 Expected output(using surface view): filedropper.com/screenshot20160520-113908 Actual output(using Framebuffer): filedropper.com/imagesbige